# In Gnome 16.04 Window minimize shortcut is not working

Tags: gnome, 16.04

I used to use <kbd>window</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to minimize a window. But it's not working. Even <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> is also not working. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl-alt-**keypad 0**? Works here.

Comment: Have you tried changing the keyboard shortcut in the keyboard shortcut settings?

Comment: @DavidFoerster --- yes, they checked --- but if look at my edit on the answer, the shortcut by default says "ctrl-alt-0", which THpubs checked --- and it worked because it is really "ctrl-alt-keypad 0" (which is not distinguishable in the setting, arguably a bug).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be these shortcuts to minimize a Window:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NUMpad 0</kbd> to minimize/restore the current window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to minimize/restore the current window
  (needs to be pressed twice if the current window is maximized)
- **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>KeyPad 0</kbd> to minimize the current window (called *Hide Window*) in the shortcut configuration panel — notice that from there you can't differentiate keypad-numbers and normal numbers, but they are different shortcut-wise.
- and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all windows.

I never heard of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to minimize windows though.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is not working. It just unmaximize the window. Won't minimize.

Comment: @THpubs If a window is maximized, pressing CTRL+SUPER+↓ *once* will restore it, but pressing it *twice* will minimize it.

Comment: Sorry it's not working.

Comment: Check the settings in **System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Windows**. There should be a shortcut setting to minimize the current window. What is that one set to?

Comment: Sorry minimize is not there.

Comment: It's  called "Hide Window" and it's assigned to Ctrl-Alt-(Keypad 0)  in my GNOME system (Notice that you can't say if a number is keypad or not in the "Shortcut" window --- but they are different. Arguably a bug).

Comment: @Rmano Great. Just accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I think Super+H should work on Ubuntu 18.04. On Ubuntu 16.04, you have to use Ctrl+Alt+0 by default, but it didn't work for me either. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I don't have NumPad panel on a laptop.
Anyway, just re-assign it in the `Keyboard settings`.